# How to Re-Populate dynamic fields?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, field

See Image below, it will allow me to add many products as I want. First I select a category from a dropdown which will then generate related entries in the Items dropdown via Ajax. I can add many products as I want by clicking on "Add Another Product".

If I finish selecting the products, I will then need to click on Submit/Order button which then validate the fields via PHP (No Ajax) before adding to the sale. If validation did not pass - I need to repopulate all the selected categories and entries (in other word create products fields again) - How to do this?

Note: All the data will be stored in `$_POST`

[image]

Comment: I would think if your JS code is at all structured you would be reusing the same methods you do at time of edit, only the values used by those functions will be coming from the persisted server-side data rather than user interactions.  Maybe not an answer but hopefully where you end up.  Like with CRUD, do you write two sets of code for create and edit scenarios or use a single base in different contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options:

- Use $_POST data to generate html containing the fields user created
- Store $_POST data (in session for example) and redirect user back to the original form which will have to include code to generate user created fields if saved data is found.

Second option is preferred.

edit: Extra info on option two.

When validation fails save $_POST data in session: `$_SESSION['stored post'] = $_POST;` and redirect to the original form (the one from which POST originated): `header('Location: /url/of/the/original-form.html);`

In the code generating the order form add following:

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['stored post']) 
     && is_array($_SESSION['stored post']) 
     && count($_SESSION['stored post']) > 0 ) //check if there is POST stored
{
    //generate fields from data stored in $_SESSION['stored post'] here

    unset($_SESSION['stored post'];  //remove the stored data
}
```

Comment: Please clarity of Second option and maybe with example.

Answer (score 0):

For input boxes, it's as easy as doing

```
<input name="fname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fname'])) echo $_POST['fname']' ?>">
```

For the selectboxes, you'll have to iterate through the options to find out which object should be SELECTED.

Comment: -1. Yes I know that but that wasnt my question. Like I said Fields are created via jQuery and related entries via Ajax.

Comment: Ah. Hmm, sorry. I'm familiar with passing forms back and forth with PHP, but shaky on jQuery and Ajax. Sorry about that.

Comment: +1. Why wouldn't you use PHP to send the client a pre-populated form if the data is in `$_POST`? You just need to add a "Remove product" button on the client-side.

Comment: @deizel When the fields are created via jQuery and Ajax. Then you click on the submit button to submit the order. If the validation failed and it will be on the same page but refreshed... all the dynamic fields will be gone.

Comment: Well, they are not gone, they are in $_POST. You can output $_POST as HTML form fields using PHP, or you can output $_POST as a Javascript array using PHP.. your choice.